# Make apps smaller / "zoom out" apps

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, high-sierra, resolution

I made my screen resolution much smaller, so now most apps look 4x larger than I'm used to.

iTunes and Finder for example are much larger than they need to be.

Can I make everything about these apps smaller?

The text, the window sizes, the icon sizes etc.

Macbook Pro w/ Retina display, mid-2015 15".

I used RDM to make my screen to 720p. Previously had been 1080p HiDPI

Comment: What tool or setting did you change when you "made screen resolution much smaller"? A little about your hardware and screen might help us help you as well.

Comment: @bmike RDM to make my screen 720p.

Comment: Thanks. I don’t know RDM but the details will surely help someone offer a better answe

Answer (score -1):

Go to the screen and right-click on the desktop. This brings up a menu and the last option is to "Show view options". Select this. You'll get a small window where you can adjust the icon size.

You can also change font size and icon spacing.

Comment: But nothing else?

Comment: i updated my answer.  Sorry.

Comment: The minimum font size is only 10. I need it smaller. Also, this doesn't change the size of the window top-bar, side-bar, or the font of the app itself (e.g. the title of the window)

Answer (score -1):

Go to System Preferences, then displays. From there you can change the Scaled sizes to your liking.

Comment: The resolution is to my liking.I just want these windows to be smaller.

Comment: @theonlygusti I don’t understand. You set the resolution to 720p, yet you want a more pixel density so that your windows will look smaller. Apple’s Retina screens are designed to give you the option to choose how big you want the scale of everything on screen while not loosing out on picture quality.

Comment: No, I don't want more pixel density. I just want the windows to use less pixels

Comment: @theonlygusti The only way to tell macOS to use less pixels for elements on the screen is to increase the amount of pixels on the screen. Is there a specific reason you want your screen at 720p?